# Invalid Parameter - VBA Chart Color

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Recently I have automated the coloring of a series of charts based off 3 key conditions. If they are "Planned", "Forced", or "Other" - the chart color will be automated rather than being a manual process. However, recently it has stopped working even though there has been no change in my code.

I reviewed my code and it has highlighted one of my modules, with the below line being the culprit supposedly.

```
ElseIf InStr(outRng.Offset(tabRowloop, 5 + ((tabcolloop - 1) * 5)), "Planned") > 0 Then                    
    serobj.Points(tabRowloop + 1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(30, 65, 100)
```

If I comment out this line, the code runs but the coloring does not work. The loop functions are fine, but I cannot understand how the coloring of my points causes an "Invalid Parameter" error.

Is anyone able to provide any guidance on what the cause could be?

```
'Code for Recolor Chart Module
Dim tabRowloop As Integer
Dim tabcolloop As Integer
Dim seriesnum As Integer
Dim serobj As Series

For tabcolloop = 1 To maxGanttBarsPerSite Step 1

    seriesnum = stupidRangeIndexThingy(tabcolloop)
    Set serobj = chobj.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(seriesnum)
    serobj.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 50, 50)

    tabRowloop = 0
    Do While Len(outRng.Offset(tabRowloop, 1))
        If (Len(outRng.Offset(tabRowloop, 1 + ((tabcolloop - 1) * 5))) > 0) Then
            Debug.Print tabRowloop & "," & tabcolloop
            If InStr(outRng.Offset(tabRowloop, 5 + ((tabcolloop - 1) * 5)), "Forced") > 0 Then
                serobj.Points(tabRowloop + 1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
            ElseIf InStr(outRng.Offset(tabRowloop, 5 + ((tabcolloop - 1) * 5)), "Planned") > 0 Then
               serobj.Points(tabRowloop + 1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(30, 65, 100)
                'problem is with the above line
            Else
                serobj.Points(tabRowloop + 1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(247, 150, 70)
            End If
        End If
        tabRowloop = tabRowloop + 1
    Loop
Next

'Sort table - Synergy first then by name
Call SortFinalTable(numUnitsFound)

'Turn on calc and redraw
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Before the "Error" line, try debugging by adding 3 lines: `Debug.Print outRng.Offset(tabRowloop, 5 + ((tabcolloop - 1) * 5)).Value` , `Debug.Print tabRowloop` and `Debug.Print tabcolloop` and see what results you are getting in the immediate window

Comment: The first 5 runs of the loop run fine, however on the sixth run of the loop - the tabcolloop value crashes with the 'invalid parameter' error. I just don't understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an Invalid Parameter error if your index for the Points object is out of range. If it fails on the first loop when tabRowLoop still equals 0, it suggests that serobj doesn't have any point. If it fails on later loops, it's because you're exceeding the number of points in the series. When stepping through the code, after the serobj variable has been set, try confirming which series has been picked up by running some debug/immediate commands.

```
print serobj.Points.Count
```